# Is it possible to add multiple accounts to a context by iterating over an input for the seed

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions

I currently have a deposit function in an app that allows deposits to individual pools and identifies each pool from an id.

The context is passed the id from the instruction so looks like:

```
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    #[instruction(poolid: u64)]
    pub struct DepositForLPTokens<'info> {
        #[account(
            seeds = [constants::POOL_SEED, poolid.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
            bump,
        )]
        pub pool: Account<'info, Pool>,
    ...
```

What I'd like to add as a feature is the ability for the user to deposit to multiple pools at once, in one transaction which would require the context to call multiple pool accounts using different ids for the seed for each one.

Is it possible to do that in one instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `remaining_accounts`.

```
pub fn multi_deposit<'info>(ctx: Context<'info, Deposits<'info>>) -> Result<()> {
     for info in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
         let pool: Acccount<Pool> = Account::try_from(info)?;

         // perform checks on pool seeds, state...etc

         // deposit
     }

    // other ops
}
```